# How to combine two different columns

Tags: google-sheets

I have two different columns with emails and I'd like to display all the emails in a separate column in the spreadsheet. Both the columns can be extended further so I can't select all cells statically. I tried doing `={(J2:J); (I2:I)}` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `=flatten(I2:J)`

The function is not officially documented,  it litteraly flatten values in an array into a single column.

Comment: i ended up using filter to filter out blank values